# Can I turn off saving in a Document Based app? (Swift for OSX)

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I'm trying to make an extremely simple note-taking app for OSX: one that can have multiple windows open and where I can quickly write down something. I don't want to store anything anywhere.
Most importantly: it should not nag about saving on quitting the app.

I'm nearly there, but I am stuck at turning off saving.
Any ideas if this is possible for a Document Based swift-app?

(using Swift and Xcode, complete NOOB at this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of applications. You can specify this when you start a new project.
Disable "create document-based application" when you start a new project and it won't nag you about saving anything.

Comment: Yeah, that worked, but now I don't have the 'new document' functionality anymore. I've looked around, but I don't find any good tutorial/example code for this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Either you have a document-based app and you would have to turn of all the document related stuff like saving that you don't need or you have a non-document based app and you create a window yourself for each note. Your app is not about documents, its about notes. So don't give the user a menu "new document" but a menu option "new note". How your represent that in your app is up to you. My advice: manage the windows yourself if you don't need the document machinery. So read the documentation about window management.

Comment: To clarify: There are lot of classes involved in the Document machinery. If you just want one window per note without saving, it's probably easier to go for the non-document route. What you learn about window management and view controllers will come in handy once you go for a document-based app.

Comment: Thanks all, I'm getting closer every time! 
I've come so far as to link a menu item to a function in the 'AppDelegate', but no clue how to create a new window now. 

I've tried to rename the class of the WindowController (and then create new NSWindow and let this be the controller), but then the app crashes on running.

Comment: Never mind, found another way to do it: in the storyboard, on the 'new' action, show window.